# What objects can be used as a datasource in Visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm frustrated with Data Sources in Visual studio.
I wan to use an object as a datasource for my report. As I understand VS understands only public properties and datatables. But I want to use a `List<Image>` from my object. Is it possible?

EDIT: For commentors. If you select an object with a table or a public property, this table is being displayed in data sources window and can be dragged onto a control or selected in reportviewer or whatever. `List<Image>` is not visible in datasource window.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE, not a framework. What are you trying to make in Visual Studio? An SSRS report? A GridView? ASP.NET? WinForms? Please include all relevant information.

Comment: "onto a control": what **type** of control? webforms? winforms? wpf? sl? xna? something else? "or selected in reportviewer": what type of report? crystal? MS? something else? "or whatever": programming rarely, if ever, deals in "whatever". The specifics matter.

Comment: Also, frankly the IDE is not usually a good way to go with this - you can connect things at runtime that **don't work** in the IDE; the runtime is **much** more flexible than the IDE. I wouldn't even bother **trying** to connect things in the IDE; it is runtime that matters.

Comment: The list just does not appear in the Data Sources window. So can not be dragged to any of them.

Comment: @Ask until you tell us the specifics, "the window" is hopelessly vague. Data-binding is **fundamentally different** between different tools.

Comment: ok, seems the question is just incorrectly formulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class implements IEnumerable Interface can be given as datasource in DOTNET
Ex: Dataset, Datatable, List, Array etc..

Comment: with the exception of .NET, most data-source binding works against `IList`, not `IEnumerable` - so we really need to know **what framework / tools** are involved. And `IList` is a gross over-simplification, since typically `ITypedList`, `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, and about 30 other types are used to implement custom binding.

Comment: i dont think so bro, http://dotnet.jku.at/courses/tutorial/03.classlibrary.pdf Find the link which says about Ienumerable and Ilist rite.. All those comes under Ienumerable(12th page) .and it says (14th page) "foreach" can used for iteration with ienumerable implemented objects-So basically all comes under IEnumerable rite.??

Comment: thanks, but I'm well aware of how `foreach` works, and the book is actually incorrect: `foreach` **does not** *require* `IEnumerable<T>` (although it can use it). That, however, is **completely unrelated** to the question of what can be used as a datasource, which typically refers to *data binding*. And to reiterate: in most (not all) cases, this *does* mean `IList` (not just `IEnumerable`).

Comment: The "datasource window" (question) is referring to specific things that are not the same as just "data I can loop over"

Comment: Purely for interest, here's an example of `foreach` without `IEnumerable` (just to show that the book is very wrong) http://pastie.org/3894366

Comment: yup, i hope so - DataRowView : ICustomTypeDescriptor, IEditableObject, IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged -> DataRowView implements these interfaces only...

Comment: *yes*, but a `DataRowView` is a leaf-level object (and here it is `ICustomTypeDescriptor` that does the fun stuff); that is typically exposed on a `DataView`, which has `ITypedList` for the metadata, and a whole ton of the other binding interfaces; interestingly, when you bind to a `DataTable` it is `IListSource` that hands over to the `DataView`  - smoke and mirrors etc. However!!!! data binding to this uses `IList` primarily. Key point: data-binding is a **lot** more complex than just `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 0):

Trying to read between the gaps in the question... it *sounds* like you want to add a `BindingSource` to the form, then on the properties for that source, select `DataSource`, select "Add Project Data Source...", select `Object`, and then expand the namespace/type-tree to select the type you will be binding.

Then at runtime, you assign the *actual* list to the `.DataSource`.

Frankly I really wouldn't bother though - just connecting it at runtime works fine, and avoids a lot of messing in the IDE.

Comment: So I select and object which has public List<Image> property and this property is not visible in DataSource window.

Comment: @Ask most data-binding, especially in the IDE, is to individual members - binding to a `List<T>` is going to be problematic *at best*, even if the tool you are using supports `Image`. You might be able to do it with chained-binding-sources, but I really don't see this ending well